# What does passing two aliases to `typedef struct` mean?

Tags: c, struct, typedef

What does `*B` in the following code mean? I understand this mixture between `typedef` and `struct`. However, this `*B` is strange.

```
typedef struct Something
{
...
}
A, *B;
```

I saw multiple questions asking about mixing `typedef` with `struct` but non of them talked about this double definition.

Comment: You know what `A` means, right?  You know what putting a `*` before a name means, right?  Put those two together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have seen this type of definition a lot in Microsoft code:

```
typedef struct {
    int count;
    char buffer[128];
} BUFFER, *PBUFFER;
```

It allows code like this to be written:

```
void read_buffer(PBUFFER pBuffer) {
    // Do something with pBuffer
}

int main(void) {
    BUFFER buffer;

    read_buffer(&buffer);
    return 0;
}
```

To directly answer your question: This kind of `typedef` allows a type and a pointer to a type to be defined at the same location in the code.

Answer (score 3):

This is a less-common use case for the `typedef` keyword that allows you to define two or more type aliases in a single line. Here, this says

- make an alias named `A` that represents the `struct` itself, and
- make an alias named `B` that represents a pointer to the `struct`.

In that sense, it's similar to writing something like

```
int A, *B;
```

Here, this declares an integer named `A` and a pointer to an integer named `B`. The syntax here involving the `*` works very similarly to what's going on in the `typedef` statement, except that instead of introducing variables it's introducing types.

Another way to see this: this is equivalent to breaking things apart into two separate statements:

```
typedef struct {
   ...
} A;

typedef A* B;
```

Here, the first one says "`A` now refers to this `struct` type, and `B` now refers to a pointer to an `A`."

Comment: Better style:  `typedef A *B;`  Remember, `*` is part of the declarator, not the underlying type, and as such it binds more closely to `B`.  This helps avoid the common mistake of  thinking that `B` and `C` have the same type in something like `typedef A* B, C;` (although this is more commonly seen in variable declarations than type definitions).

Comment: @TomKarzes That is a reasonable point - thanks for bringing it up. I've seen different companies and style guides handle this in different ways for different reasons, with the usual advice being "be consistent with whatever the codebase you're working with is doing."

Comment: For purely stylistic things, I tend to agree, although I would argue that improper grouping borders on a correctness issue, which trumps style guidelines.  In any case, OP's post didn't have this problem.  I like to avoid teaching new programmers bad habits.  I often see `char* a, b;` followed by "Why does `a = b;` give an error?"

Comment: Fwiw, my personal styleguide says "Don't typedef pointer types. Writing out the stars takes no more keystrokes than a `P` prefix, and is much clearer." (Clearer for me, anyway.)

Comment: @rici That makes sense, although the specific point I was making is much more likely to occur with ordinary, non-typedef declarations (e.g., `char* a, b;` vs. `char *a, b;`.  The latter is clear, but the former is not.  I always consider mis-grouping parts of a declarator to be bad style.

Comment: @tom: yeah, the two issues are orthogonal. I'm not a big fan of combining different types in the same declaration at all, and even when I do that, I would normally put the scalar types first to avoid confusion (`int val, *ptr;`). I always insist that two or more identifiers declared together be strongly related. But all that is just me. I do try hard to only inject my prejudices when I'm convinced they have a solid basis, and I do believe that for the case of typdef'ing pointers. A declaration of a pointer type should, IMO, visibly be a declaration of a pointer type...

Comment: ...and the relationship between a type and a pointer to that type should be visibly obvious, which is hard to do when they are represented by different names and easy to do when one of them is written with a star.